# Remove label from solaris disk

Tags: solaris

As you know, any disk used in Solaris has to have a label (if there isn't any, you can just use "format").

My problem is I want to *unlabel*  a disk for testing purposes. Is there any command that does this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering myself here:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=$HARDDRIVE count=16
```

This overwrites the label, and a "format label" is required in order for the drive to be usable again.

Comment: How do you know which $HARDDRIVE value to use ? I've tried 

dd if=/dev/zero of=/pci@0/pci@0/pci@2/scsi@0/sd@0,0 count=16, witouth success...

Comment: @Kami I currently have no Solaris box available, but if I'm not mistaken, I used the output of `format` to see which device I needed

Answer (score 1):

I always used a linux life CD to remove all partitions and repartition the disk. That will remove all labels. That, ofcourse is only an option if the disk content is disposable... ;-)

Comment: The disk contents are garbage. Is there an appropriate command on Solaris?

Comment: Not that I know. Thats why I used knoppix or ubuntu...

Comment: ... to "erase" the labels...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you found your solution, but dd is a sledgehammer hitting a nail.  Take a look at the man page for fmthard, I think it's a little more elegant, and supported.

Comment: Doesn't look like it's capable of deleting a label, only placing one.

Answer (score 0):

dd if=/dev/zero of=$HARDDRIVE count=16 will not work if it is efi label, we have to change to smi label and then run dd to remove label:

```
format -e $HARDDRIVE
select l, and 0 (for SMI label)
dd if=/dev/zero of=$HARDDRIVE count=16enter code here
prtvtoc $HARDDRIVE ( check partition map, it should give invalid vtoc)
```

Comment: What code is someone supposed to enter there?

Comment: doenst wipefs work also?